# Problemas de tradução na janela de flags

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

3 problemas de tradução na janela de flags e no novo recurso de tirar flag:

- You already have a pending flag on this answer
- This is the flag you currently have raised
- Retract Flag

[image: Screenshot]

Atualizado em 1/09/2016, aparentemente resolvido, testado no meta e no site principal.

[image: screenshot atualizado, aparentemente corrigido]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está traduzido no [Transifex do SOpt](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/) (todo mundo pode ajudar). Falta revisar e mandar para o novo *build*. Ainda dá para melhorar, por isso aceito sugestões:

> You already have a pending flag on this answer

Você já tem uma sinalização pendente nesta resposta

> This is the flag you currently have raised

Esta é a sua sinalização

> Retract Flag

Retirar sinalização

Comment: As traduções ainda não foram atualizadas no site. O @Gabe precisa aprovar pra elas atualizarem?

Comment: Ele precisa passar para a aplicação. Algumas pessoas são revisores e podem aprovar, eu até poderia aprovar mas prefiro que outra pessoa faça.